# Eregi Validation Issue

Tags: php, regex, validation, expression, eregi

I've been reading and reading on regular expressions, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
if(eregi("^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]$", $username)){return true;}
```

It never returns true. I'm trying to validate usernames and only allow lowercase a-z, uppercase a-z, numbers, hyphens and underscores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eregi()` is deprecated. Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

You have no [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (such as `/`, `@`, `~`, etc).

Use `preg_match('/^[\w-]+\z/')`.

- `/` is the delimiter I have used. PHP allows you to use [many other characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).
- `\w` is a shortcut to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It is useful here to make the regex shorter and hopefully clearer.
- Inside of a character class, if the `-` is not part of a valid range, it will be taken literally. I have not escaped it because it does not required being escaped in this scenario.
- `+` is a quantifier that says *match 1 or more times*. You need that here.
- `\z` means match end of string. You used `$`, which will allow a trailing `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`eregi`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) - it is deprecated, use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/i$", $username)){return true;}
```

Comment: Why `i` pattern modifier and explicitly `A-Za-z` ?

Comment: @alex `i` is for a case _insensitive_ search, which `eregi` does, and should be included.

Comment: @mc10: But the answer already covers `A-Za-z` in the character class.

Comment: @alex, I've just copied the former regular expression. The main point in my answer is that the OP should not use `eregi` and I suppose @Jack would figure out the rest himself.